# Question about a proof of the 0-1 law

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-limit-theorems

[image]

---

I was reading this textbook *Some Random Series of Functions* by Jean Pierre Kahane. The attached scripts come from the page $9$ in the book.

**My first question** is why we have the equality in the red bracket?

**My second question is**, given a general random variable $X$ and a real number $r$, why we have $\mathscr{P}(X>r)$ is either $0$ or $1$?

I guess there must be some gaps which he omitted and I can't fill up. Thanks for help.

Comment: I'm not sure either about the first question. This theorem is called Kolmogorov's zero-one law, and the simplest proof that I know of uses the $\pi-\lambda$ theorem to conclude that $A$ is independent of itself. See page 81 of https://services.math.duke.edu/~rtd/PTE/PTE5_011119.pdf

Comment: @Mason Thanks for providing an alternative proof. Actually I have another proof from my professor but I just want to understand this specific one. Thanks.

Comment: @Mason I guess the definition of $A$ is crucial which I don't quite understand. $A$ is defined to be an event which does not depend on the values of any finite number of $X_n$. Do you know what it means by saying an event doesn't depend on a bunch of random variables?

Comment: It means that $A \in \mathcal{T} := \cap_{n = 1}^{\infty}\sigma(X_{k} : k \geq n)$. $\mathcal{T}$ is called the tail $\sigma$-algebra of the sequence $(X_n)$. Here $X_n(\omega) = \omega_n$.